# Boolean method to determine if a given matrix is identity matrix

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array, boolean

I'm given a matrix [][]a, int size and int x. I need to write a method which takes the a[x][x] element and returns true if it is the top-left corner cell of an identity matrix in the given size.
for example if a is :

```
 {{1 0 0 0}, 
 {1 0 1 0},
 {0 0 1 0},
 {0 0 0 1}}
```

size = 2, x = 2 - the method will return true, as a[2][2] is the top-left element of identity matrix 2x2.

Below is what I've been working on. The logic is: if current element is 1 and exactly size-1 elements below  and left to current element are equal to 0, I move on to next element in the diagonal, while reducing size by 1 with every step.
The method returns true for a =

```
{{1,0,0},
{0,1,0},
{0,0,1}}
```

size = 3, x = 0.
However, if a[2][0] == 1 the method still returns true, and if a[1][0] == 1 it returns false as expected.
Can anyone assist spotting the logic flaws here? much appreciated.
Also, the method must not include any kind of loops, recursion only.

```
public static boolean isIdentity(int[][]a, int size, int x){
    return isIdentity(a, size, x, a[x][x]);
}
private static boolean isIdentity(int[][]a, int size, int x, int current){
    if(size == 0){
        return true;
    }
    if(size < 0 || x > a.length-1 || x > a[0].length-1){
        return false;
    }
    boolean t = false;
    if(current == 1 && x + 1 < a.length && allZeros(a,size-1,a[x+1][x],a[x][x+1],x)){
        t =  isIdentity(a,size-1, x,a[x+1][x+1]);
    }
    return t;
}
private static boolean allZeros(int[][]a, int size, int current_down, int current_right,int x){
    if(current_down != 0 || current_right != 0){
        return false;
    }
    if(size == 0){
        return true;
    }
   return allZeros(a, size - 1, a[x+1][x],a[x][x+1],x);
    
}
```

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* thing this does wrong?

Comment: Why does a in the example return true? The top left corner is not a 2x2 identity matrix? Is it just that that first element matches?

Comment: Can you explain what `allZeros` is supposed to be computing?

Comment: @ScottHunter allZeros checks all the elements to the right and below current element and returns if they are all equal to zero, false otherwise

Comment: Is the end goal to check if the top left matrix of size 2 in a is an identity matrix? I have a way that I think works in that case.

Comment: @RichardKYu: Only if x=0 and size=2

Comment: @ScottHunter Oh I get it now, the x is specifying the starting position

Comment: @oryan7: Then it doesn't seem like it should have 2 recursive calls in it.

Comment: @RichardKYu yes, x is starting position.

Comment: @ScottHunter you're right! I've fixed my code, will edit it now. however, it still doesn't work :/

Comment: @oryan7 But with starting position 2,2 don't you get a[2][2]=0, meaning it should return false?

Comment: @notice I've given 2 matrices . in the first one a[2][2] == 1, in the second one indeed it is equal to 0, however x = 0. so we're starting at a[0][0].

Comment: Define what `allZeros` does in terms of its arguments; then apply that definition to where you call it recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to define `allZeros` using the following definition:

`allZeros(a,size,x,i)` = "`a[x+1..x+i][x]` and `a[x][x+1..x+i]` are all 0s"

When `i=size`, this equivalent to all of both edges (not including the corner) are 0.

Then your task becomes:

- What can I initialze `i` to be to make this trivially true?
- What do I need to do so that solving for the "next" `i` (i.e. the recursive call) solves the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to a different recursive implementation, here is my take on it:

```
public class CheckIdentity {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] a = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, 
            {1, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1}};

    int [][] b = {{1,0,0},
        {0,1,0},
        {0,0,1}};
    int [][] b_2 = {{1,0,0},
        {0,1,0},
        {1,0,1}};

    System.out.println(isIdentity(a, 2, 2));
    System.out.println(isIdentity(b, 3, 0));
    System.out.println(isIdentity(b_2, 3, 0));

    }
    
    public static boolean isIdentity(int [][]a, int size, int x) {
    return isIdentity(a, x+size,x, x,x);
    }

    public static boolean isIdentity(int[][] a, int size, int x, int r, int c) {
    int rI = (r + (c+1)/size);
    int cI = (c+1)==size ? x : c+1;
    
    //System.out.println(r + " " +c + " "+rI + " "+cI);
    
    if (r==size) {
        return true;
    }
    
    else if(r==c && a[r][c]==1) {
        return true && isIdentity(a, size, x, rI,cI);
    }
    else if(r!=c && a[r][c]==0) {
        return true && isIdentity(a, size, x, rI,cI);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    }

}
```

The idea is we go to the next row only when we reach the specified size of the matrix. Further, if we go to a new row, our column will start back at x, the initial position of the column.

Since we are guaranteed to start on an index of a diagonal of the matrix, we can check when r is equal to c to determine whether the entry should be 1 or 0.

Output:

```
true
true
false
```